# MouseWheelDown event fires multiple times in succession

Tags: delphi, mousewheel

Delphi 7 on Windows 7

I want to scroll down a list (TElTree) using the mouse wheel... so I start writing some code in the ElTree's OnMouseWheelDown event. Then I notice that it's scrolling 2 rows at once. The mouse wheel settings in Control Panel are set to scroll only 1 line at a time. If I place a breakpoint inside the event handler, I discover that the event handler is itself being executed twice in quick succession.... Why? How to ensure it only executes once (code please)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the wheel scrolls, the OS sends [`WM_MOUSEWHEEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645617.aspx) messages. The high-order word of the `wParam` parameter indicates *how far* the wheel has turned. If it has turned one "click," then its value will be 120, or `WHEEL_DELTA`. But it might be less than that if your scroll wheel recognizes scrolling less than a click's worth.

Correct `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message handlers need to consider that parameter and either keep a "scrolling accumulator" to keep track of how far the wheel has scrolled or else have the ability to scroll less than a full line. Message handlers that *assume* that each message signifies a full click of the wheel will be sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'll delve deeper.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is quite simple: After calling the function you want to perform `OnMouseWheel` you must set `Handled:=True` so that the routine is not called multiple times. e.g.

```
procedure TMainForm.FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  YourFunctionToExecute(Sender, Shift, MousePos, Handled);
  Handled:=True;
end;
```

Comment: Quick and CLEAR. This should be the accepted answer. Thanks. +1